# Как работать с исключения на php?

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как работать с исключениями на PHP? Раньше, я работал с Python, и там все было просто:

```
try:
   ...
except:
   ...
```

Мой скрипт получает данные по API в JSON объекте, мне нужно сделать условие, которое будет проверять, если json объект ничего не вернул - подождать 10 секунд и попробовать еще раз.

На Python это решалось очень легко:

```
try:
   url = "http://site..........
   with urlopen(url) as response:
   .....
except:
   time.sleep(10)
```

Как сделать подобное исключение на PHP я не до конца понимаю.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: А где у вас на питоне "попробовать ещё раз"?

Comment: @vp_arth тут скорее не "попробовать еще раз", а пройтись по циклу еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

Обработка исключений в PHP мало чем отличается от других Си-подобных языков.

```
try {
  $url = "";
  // some code

} catch (\Exception $e) { // (\Throwable $e) в php7
  sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: не С++ подобных, а Си подобных

Comment: А как по вашему исключения обрабатываются в самом Си?